# what is the code or syntax to move items in the navbar to the right

Tags: html, css

I want to know how to move the `nav` bar to the right. As of now, with the current HTML I have posted, it displays all of the items in the navbar to the left.  I would like to place some of the items to the right but I am not sure how to do this. For example, should I use CSS? Or should I use a keyword in bootstrap? Please note that I am using bootstrap.

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark ">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Store Shop</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault"
        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse ml-auto" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home
                    <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="register.html">Create Account</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="navmoveright">
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" id="navmoveright">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" aria-label="Enter Username">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" aria-label="Enter Password">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" name="submit" type="submit">Login</button>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right mr-auto" id="navmoveright">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span> Cart (0)</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
.navmoveright{
    float:right;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Try replacing your "navmoveright" class with the bootstrap "ml-auto" class. This sets the margin-left to auto, which should move your navigation to the right.

Comment: I have tried the ml-auto but that didn't work.  I seems that something in the code is keeping it from moving right.  However, do not know what it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
```

It appears that the issue was with the two CDN'S that I had placed.  After I deleted the 4.0 version the code and syntax was able to work the way it is suppose to.  In other words the two cdn's seemed to be conflicting with each other.

Answer (score 0):

add this `css`

```
.navmoveright
{
  float:right;
}
```

i hope this will helps

Comment: Tried the float but it did not set the element of the navbar to the right

Comment: can you share your your css files so we can figure out proper solution